# Forward variadic argument to thread with lambda

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, variadic-templates, generic-lambda

I'm having trouble finding how use `std::thread()` with lambdas. Namely, with having a variadic argument lambda receive the arguments by forwarding. As an example:

```
template<typename... T> 
auto foo(T&&... t){
    [](T&&... t){}(std::forward<T>(t)...); // (1)

    return std::thread( // (2) 
        [](T&&... t){},
        std::forward<T>(t)...
    );
}

auto bar(){
    int n=1;
    foo(1); (A)
    foo(n); (B)
}
```

A.1: compiles

A.2: compiles

B.1: compiles

B.2: **doesn't compile**

I don't understand:

- Why the `std::thread()` (2) version using (B) doesn't compile and (A.2) does?
- Why are there differences between (B.1) and (B.2)

Comment: It should be `std::forward<T>(t)...`. I'm not sure that helps with your case since you have a single-element pack, but still.

Comment: I think it's equivalent as the error persists but edited to have that cleaner syntax ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
template<typename... T> 
auto foo(T&&... t){
    [](T&&... u){ }(std::forward<T>(t)...); // (1)

    return std::thread( // (2) 
        [](auto &&... u){ },
        std::forward<T>(t)...
    );
}
```

I mean: in the lambda you pass to `std::thread()`, `auto && ...` instead of `T && ...`. Or, maybe, `T const & ...`.

I'm not a language layer, and maybe someone can correct me, but it seems to me that there is a clash between universal references and r-value references. And the fact that `std::thread()` pass **copies** of the following arguments to the first one.

When you write

```
template<typename... T> 
auto foo(T&&... t)
```

the `&&` are universal-references and `T...` become `int`, when you call `foo(1)`, and `int &`, when you call `foo(n)`.

Inside the function you get

```
[](int){ }(std::forward<int>(t)); // (1)

return std::thread( // (2) 
    [](int){ },
    std::forward<int>(t)...
);
```

in case `f(0)`.

And this works because both lambda are waiting a `int` by copy and this ever works.

But when you call `f(n)`, inside `foo()` you get

```
[](int &){ }(std::forward<int>(t)); // (1)

return std::thread( // (2) 
    [](int &){ },
    std::forward<int>(t)...
);
```

and this works for the first call, because the lambda wait a `int` left-reference variable (`int &`) and get a `int` left-reference variable, but doesn't works for the second call because `std::thread` pass a **copy** of `std::forward<int>(t)` (so a right-reference, `int &&`) to the lambda that wait for a left-reference.

Answer (score 2):

`std::thread` can't simply forward its arguments to the lambda by reference, because that would mean two threads potentially having simultaneous access to the arguments without synchronisation. So instead, `std::thread` creates temporary copies of the arguments, and passes those to the lambda. Because they are temporaries, they are rvalues. This works in A.2 because the lambda's parameter is an rvalue reference (because `T` is `int`, so `T&&` is `int&&`). It doesn't work in B.2, because the lambda's parameter is an lvalue reference (because `T` is `int&`, so `T&&` is `int&`). Like max66 says, you probably want to use `auto&&...` in your lambda so it can accept whatever is passed to it.